# Add timestamp to cat output from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, cat

I have a small script that cats the output from the ttyUSB to a file I would like to prepend a timestamp to each line. From the command line this does everything I want:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 /home/pi/daily_logs/ttyUSSB0 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }
```

My issue is that when I add it to a script everything works but the awk timestamp isn't added. My script line looks like this:

```
cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /home/pi/daily_logs/ttyUSB0 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; } &
```

Any help getting this going would be appreciated.

Comment: get rid of the ">". Then get rid of the UUOC.

Comment: You might find my `timer` command useful: https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/kst-time-utils

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to redirect awk's output to the file, not cat's. The way you have it, awk gets nothing. Actually, [you may not need cat at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16279/should-i-care-about-unnecessary-cats):

```
awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }' /dev/ttyUSB0 > /home/pi/daily_logs/ttyUSB0 &
```

Comment: Happy to push you over ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: Awesome thank you, I have a lot more reading to do. Follow up question. Now that I have this running without cat, how to I stop it if I want to roll the file over at end of the day? Currently I am looking for the cat pids st

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the > /home/pi/daily_logs/ttyUSB0 after the pipe.  Like so:

`cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }'  > /home/pi/daily_logs/ttyUSB0`

Answer (score 0):

Useless use of cat is impeding the solution.  To minimize the changes needed, you can also do:

```
< /dev/ttyUSB0 > /home/pi/daily_logs/ttyUSB0 awk '...' &
```