# Format output of xentop

Tags: linux, cmd, grep, format

The command `xentop -bi1` outputs the following:

```
NAME  STATE   CPU(sec) CPU(%)     MEM(k) MEM(%)  MAXMEM(k) MAXMEM(%) VCPUS NETS NETTX(k) NETRX(k) VBDS   VBD_OO   VBD_RD   VBD_WR  VBD_RSECT  VBD_WSECT SSID
  Domain-0 -----r      37719    0.0    2096776    6.4   no limit       n/a     1    0        0        0    0        0        0        0          0          0    0
  testvm01 --b---         69    0.0     131072    0.4     131072       0.4     1    1     2388     1670    2        0     3358    15802     154314     273808    0
xenwin2008 --b---       8208    0.0    1052628    3.2    1052672       3.2     1    2     1361        0    2        0        0        0          0          0    0
```

I want to output only the cpu usage of testvm01

So, i use grep: `xentop -bi1 | grep testvm01`

```
testvm01 --b---         69    0.0     131072    0.4     131072       0.4     1    1     2389     1672    2        0     3358    15826     154314     274080    0
```

How to get only the value "0.0"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
xentop -bi1 | awk '$1 == "testvm01" { print $4 }'
```

It yields:

```
0.0
```

Comment: How could I append a time-stamp  to the output of this code: xentop -bi10 | awk '$1 == "testvm01" { print $4 }'

Comment: @Ali: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161552/add-timestamp-to-cat-output-from-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
xentop -bi1 | awk '/testvm01/{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another variation of `awk`

```
xentop -bi1 | awk '$1~/testvm01/ {print $4}'
0.0
```